# custom database query in sharepoint using active directory username as filter

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, filter, performancepoint

i have a custom query in a database which i want to display to users in a MOSS via performancepoint webpart.

I need to filter the report based on the username of the logged in user. 
How can i pass the AD username to the performancepoint webpart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the BPM.ServerConnectionPerUser property in your web.config files (PPS sites, as well as any SharePoint site using a PPS webpart) to True.  Do an IISReset after you do that, and you should be hunky dory.

The reason is that default behavior for PPS is to use the application pool identity to hit all of your data sources, which is a nightmare if your source is a cube (what happened to member level security?!?).  Luckily, changing the ServerConnectionPerUser property to True enables this.  Nick Barclay went into this quite well on his [blog post](http://nickbarclay.blogspot.com/2008/01/pps-data-connection-security-with.html) on the subject.

Cheers,
Eric